# Unable to insert some unicode characters in latex

Tags: fonts, unicode

I have to insert the following string in a my latex work: ˈtʃæptə(r)
I tried to switch from pdfLatex to LuaLatex and XeLatex but some characters are still not rendered. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: characters can only be rendered if the font you are using contains suitable glyphs. So select the right font, see the documentation of fontspec about how to do it.

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` may helps you...

Comment: @MadyYuvi : don't use that with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I agreed your words, what I suggested is suits with `PDFLaTeX`, I missed to mention it...

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine with xelatex or lualatex and a recent version of TeX Live:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\begin{document}
tʃæptə(r)
\end{document}
```

I assume it will work with other recent TeX distributions too.